# AJAX Not Responding

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

So I'm trying to just alert out my "Hello" from my php file, it's pretty straight forward but it's not working for some reason.

**JS**

```
    function dynamic()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {   
            window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "hello.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
}

dynamic();
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
echo "Hello";
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="dynamic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

test

</body>
</html>
```

I can't get the alert box to alert my "Hello". It should just come straight from responseText.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why use a POST request if you not sending any data? GET is simpler and more straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't invoke `send` method. It sends the request <sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29)</sup>

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

If you want to put any data in POST put it in send methods parameter as urlencoded form.

```
xmlhttp.send("foo=bar&hello=world");
```

Comment: So I always have to send something, even if null?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes, Because it sends the requests

Comment: @david right you are. I always used `null` for GET, so I wrote that. Actually it does not require it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function dynamic()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {   
            window.alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "hello.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

dynamic();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to send the request:

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
```

or

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
```

instead of

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and you have to put

```
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

beside [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9799131/230205), logging in php file is a useful behaviour in similar situations.